Quarto 20:60:20 html layout on multiple screens
I am unable to achieve a reasonable layout of quarto html output. On wide screens there are 2 extra spaces left/right on top of standard sidebar / margin, and I am loosing TOC when playing with column-page etc. features. Layout full with TOC makes the content not centered...
I would simply want left 20% of the screen, on all screen sizes, to be a sidebar with TOC, middle 60% to be the content, and right 20% to be (empty) margin. Do not know how to achieve that.
grid:
sidebar-width: 20%
body-width: 60%
margin-width: 20%
fails on some preset in px which is not compatible with %. No combination of grid setting in pixels achieved the desired output.
I am using Quarto 1.4.554
Example:

Simply use a 3 column grid and don't use the 3rd column


.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
  gap: .25em;
}

aside {
  background: lightblue;
}

main {
  background: lightgreen;
}
<div class="container">
  <aside>Sidebar</aside>
  <main>Main Content</main>
</div>




I have lost TOC, there are still some margins left and right from the specified div, the body is definitely not 60% and the thing is not even centered. Total disarray.

Then you will have to provide a [mcve]


title: Quarto Template
format:
html:
toc: true
toc-location: left
self-contained: true
embed-resources: true
editor_options:
chunk_output_type: console


Sidebar

Quarto
Quarto .... https://quarto.org.
DT
library(kableExtra)

data(mtcars)

kable(mtcars)



Sorry I couldnt put it properly into the question, it just keeps claiming I have wrong formatting and does not let me post it. But it is quarto...

simply use a 2-column layout where youa dd a right-margin of 20vw. Then you can split the remain 80vw in a "1fr 3fr" split:


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0 20vw 0 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
}

aside {
  width: 20vw;
  border: 2px dashed blue;
}

main {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}
<body>
  <aside>Sidebar</aside>
  <main>Content</main>
</body>



